# Count Number of instances of text in a text file - VB

Tags: vb.net, file, parsing, text, delimited

I have a need to parse a large, delimited text file (28 million lines plus) and count the number of instances of a particular piece of text in the text file using VB 2015.

The structure of the lines is thus;

> 123|WD7|ELU|SOD|010116
>   456|WD9|LFT|AST|010116
>   135|WD7|TFT|THY|010116
>   154|AED|ELU|SOD|030116

etc, etc....

My exact requirements are to identify each of the entries in delimited field 2 and delimited field 4 and then count the number of instances of each.

So from the lines above, the items in field 2 would be WD7, WD9 and AED and the number of instances would be WD7 x 2, WD9 x 1 and AED x 1.

Similarly, the items in field 4 would be SOD, AST, THY and SOD and the number of instances would be SOD x 2, THY x 1, AST x 1.

The items in field 2 and field 4 will not be known prior to parsing the file and indeed the parsing is to identify what text is contained in these fields and how many times.

Hopefully that is clear and many thanks for any guidance.

Steve

Comment: Did you have a question or are you just updating us ala Twitter?

Comment: Have you actually tried anything yourself?

Comment: Just for one field, you can duplicate for two. Make dictionary of string, int. Read the file line by line, split each line by | into an array. Check the array at the appropriate index and then check the dictionary for that string. If doesn't exist, add a new entry in dictionary of the string and 1. If it already exists, increment the dictionary entry where the string matches. Or split then load all the strings at the appropriate index into an array. Then use LINQ to group by the string, and sum the items.

Comment: Many thanks, I should have said that I am a self learning amateur at the moment and I have not tried the full exercise yet as I simply didn't know how to. I have got to the status of selecting file, reading file line by line, splitting line by delimiters but i simply didn't know how to approach the checking items and counting items component. I will research and try your suggestions. These were the guidance prompts I absolutely required and I am extremely grateful for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Dim textfile As String = "C:/test/test.txt"
Dim stream_reader As New StreamReader(textfil_file)
Dim line As String
line = stream_reader.ReadLine()
Do While Not (line Is Nothing)
        Dim parts As String() = line.Split("|")
        For Each part In parts
            'display them in msgboxes or do whatever you like with them

            MsgBox(part(1))
            MsgBox(part(3))
        Next
    line = stream_reader.ReadLine()
Loop
stream_reader.Close()
```